# Filtered data Download using Active Admin Axlsx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, activeadmin

I am using **active-admin-axlsx** gem for excel download in Rails 4 app using **active-admin**.
A user can filter the data he views on the screen.

For example, if I have 10 records for user **ABC** and 5 records for user **XYZ**, I want to see records only for **XYZ**, I have the filters setup using the filters provided by active admin.

What I now want is to download only these records that I have filtered, in the excel rather than all the 15 records of both ABC and XYZ.

As of now the default behaviour is the excel download contains all the records, irresepective of the filters.

Please suggest how can I achieve only filtered data download in the excel

Many Thanks!